# Deployment of community without the binary files

Tags: community, salesforcedx

We are using salesforce dx to deploy community changes. In order to do so, we have two binary SiteDotCom files in the repository.

The issue with that is those files are not human readable. So they can not be merged. And furthermore, when we do deployment, what often happens is our changes in orgs can potentially be overwritten due to this as we are not sure what are inside those files.

To mitigate this, we have exported the community pages and templates in our github repo. But we are still relying on those two files to get things deployed.

Is there a method to get rid of those files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Spring 20 release , the [experience bundle metadata](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_networks_developers_exp.htm) is going to be in GA and you might want to look into it .

> Previously, the Network, CustomSite, and SiteDotCom metadata types combined to define a community. However, retrieving the SiteDotCom type produces a binary .site file, which isn’t human readable. By retrieving the ExperienceBundle type instead of SiteDotCom, you can extract granular community metadata in a human-readable format, contained in a three-level folder structure.

1.First step is to enable the experience metadata type using below steps

Enter ***Communities Settings*** in the Quick Find box, and then select Communities Settings.

Select Enable ExperienceBundle Metadata API, and save your changes.

2.You can use sfdx cli to retrieve [ExperienceBundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm) metadata

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "ExperienceBundle"
```

Comment: Thanks for that and that's very helpful. Does that mean now we can deploy the community changes with the ExperienceBundle and put the binary files into .gitignore?

Comment: @Lance shi yes that's true. You might not need that binary anymore

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Were you able to deploy a community using the ExperienceBundle? I constantly get the following error "Error: selfRegistrationRouteId in QA1/config/qA.json doesn't contain a valid Route ID. Check the value and try again." So I created a community manually, retrieved the metadata using ant and later I made some minor changes and tried to deploy but I still see the above error.

Comment: @SriramLns Could you raise a case with salesforce support for the error ? could be a bug!

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I've created a case, so far the outcome is that we cannot deploy a community created in one org to another. We have to create a community in an org, export it, make changes and deploy to the same org.